# Users queue in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, queue

I'm trying to create queues table

```
id | queue_id | user_id | is_active_to_vote
1  | 14       | 1       | 1
2  | 14       | 2       | 0
3  | 14       | 3       | 0
4  | 15       | 1       | 1
5  | 15       | 2       | 0
6  | 15       | 3       | 0
```

the users list in result  looks like this (for queue_id=14)

```
Sam (user_id=1 votes now)
John (user_id=2)
Bill (user_id=3)
```

But if user did not vote in time I need to resort the queue like this

```
John (user_id=2 votes now)
Bill (user_id=3)
...
Sam (user_id=1 last user in queue)
```

What is the good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using "did not vote in time" information in order to sort your queue, you need that information on voting time somewhere - either in a new field in your current table, or in a separate table.

Once you have that, you'll be able to sort the queue based on the criteria you want (which aren't clear to me at this point - is it `user_id` by default ?).

Note that in general I would advise you to perform queue management in your application controller, not directly in MySQL.